# javascript how to validate a users numeric input and output its type

Tags: javascript, validation

I am trying to figure out if there is a javascript function that can validate users numeric input and output its type in a

. Would match function work? Or is there a function that can validate a users input and out put if it is a phone number, social security numeric or zip code? I researched it and could not find a exactly what I need for this, found validation to ensure user is inputting numbers or letters but not process to verify its type depending on its length or special characters in it. I do not have much experience, I hope my question makes sense.

```
    <h1>Reg Test</h1>
</header>
<br>
<p><b>Enter numeric value:</b></p>
<input id="inp" type="text">
<br>
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="pros()">Process</button>
<br>
<p id="iop"></p>
<br>
<script>
    function pros() {

        var numt = document.getElementById("inp").value;


    }
</script>
```

Comment: i think you can assign a class to every `input` field and provide validations according to it.

Comment: If you provide the rules for what is a phone number, what is a social security number, etc. it might be possible. Phone number formats vary quite a bit, so likely only viable for a particular country or region. Zip and postcodes vary quite a bit too from country to country, so more rules required.

Comment: Rob, thats what I was thinking. Thought I'd ask in case there was anther way to perform this task. I only have the one iput field, so I was thinking I could do IF statements to idetify each type of number combination. How can I have it check for how many digits are in the input? for example a phone number would be 10 characters, social would be 9, zip would be 5.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".isInteger").keypress(function(){
 return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="isInteger" type="text" />
```